# Why does my Navbar not display as intended in Google Chrome, but works on other browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, navbar

I created a website with a transparent navbar placed on top of a full-background slider. When the display width is reduced the slider is hidden and the navbar appears on a dark background when toggled open. The page content drops down when the navbar opens. This is how it functions in Safari and Firefox.

The problem occurs when viewed in Chrome. The page opens correctly, but, when scrolling, the navbar appears above the background slider, so that it's no longer transparent. It looks like a dark blue band containing the navbar appears at the top of the page. This is actually the page background color, because the navbar is now on top of the background slider. I corrected that by adding `position: absolute` to the CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The full-size view looks fine now in all browsers, but when viewed in sm or sx size, the navbar links appear on a transparent background overlapping the page content when toggled open. The page content no longer drops down to accommodate the opened navbar. Is there any way to make the navbar display correctly in all sizes in Chrome and other browsers?

- Original site that does not work on Chrome: http://mcgsf.net.
- Updated site that works in all browsers at full size, but not sm or sx: http://mcgsf.net/test081017/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at http://mcgsf.net in chrome, I noticed the background image jumps into place after the transition. Looking at the css for `.carousel .item`, you set `position: fixed` but haven't set any explicit position for it. So its position is fixed relative to its container, which happens to be positioned relatively to the navbar. I think you want the carousel item to be always fixed to the top. Setting `position: absolute` on the navbar accomplishes this because the navbar no longer affects other relatively positioned elements, but this has the unintended side effect of not having those elements respond to the expanding menu.

Instead, set `top: 0` on `.carousel .item` (and remove the negative margin) to fix it to the top of the window. Then, you don't need to mess with your navbar.